List<DataRow>.DefaultIfEmpty() shows error
I need to get a new DataRow from the List<DataRow> object.
Data object has 5 records / rows.
public List<DataRow> Data { get; set; } = new();

private DataRow GetDataRow(COAClassRecord _Record)
{
    DataRow _DataRow = (DataRow)Data.DefaultIfEmpty();
    _DataRow["Id"] = _Record.ID;
    _DataRow["Code"] = _Record.Code;
    _DataRow["Title"] = _Record.Title;
    return _DataRow;
}

But I got an error on this line:
DataRow _DataRow = (DataRow)Data.DefaultIfEmpty();



System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'DefaultIfEmptyIterator`1[System.Data.DataRow]' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Kindly help me to find out how can I get a new DataRow through List<>.DefaultifEmpty or give be better way.

read the exception text

Data is a List of DataRow that can contain multiple elements, not a single object. Which one of them do you want to access ?

Perhaps you're looking for .FirstOrDefault() or  .SingleOrDefault() instead of .DefaultIfEmpty()?

"I need to get a new DataRow" - maybe you want to create a new DataRow object and add it to the list ? Please clarify.

It's clear that DefaultIfEmpty is not what you should be calling there, because you specifically state that the list is not empty. You need to explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just show us code that doesn't achieve it. "I need to get a new DataRow from the List object" makes no sense, so that's not a description. If you want a new DataRow then you get it from a DataTable. If you want an existing DataRow from the list then that's a different thing, but which of the five rows do you want? EXPLAIN.

Data is a list object.

Make sure there is a default DataRow in case your returning list is empty. With that, you can use FirstOrDefault to get the DataRow from IEnumerable with Type <T>.
First, create a class in C# like below :
public class COAClassRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

Then, Refer it to your program like below :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Sample example = new Sample();
        COAClassRecord record = new COAClassRecord { ID = 1, Code = "ABC", Title = "Sample Title" };
        DataRow row = example.GetDataRow(record);        
        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {row["Id"]}, Code: {row["Code"]}, Title: {row["Title"]}");
    }
}

public class Sample
{
    public List<DataRow> Data { get; set; } = new();

    public DataRow GetDataRow(COAClassRecord _Record)
    {
        DataRow _DataRow = Data.DefaultIfEmpty(CreateDefaultDataRow()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (_DataRow != null)
        {
            _DataRow["Id"] = _Record.ID;
            _DataRow["Code"] = _Record.Code;
            _DataRow["Title"] = _Record.Title;
        }
        return _DataRow;
    }

    private DataRow CreateDefaultDataRow()
    {
        
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));

        
        return table.NewRow();
    }
}


Refer the working .netfiddle here


Note that's going to create a new row every time you call it whether or not it's necessary, and why the unnecessary table? Just conditionally call NewRow on your existing table _DataRow = Data.FirstOrDefault() ?? _cachedDefaultRow;
